# MongoDB - Categorical text index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Does it matter to MongoDB if the text field is categorical when it creates the index? That is, the index is text, but only can support a finite set of values.

Ex.

```js
{
  v_ :
      { g_e : 'VH1' }
},

{
  v_ :
      { g_e : 'VH2' }
}
```

Currently I'm just doing,

```js
db.coll.createIndex({'v_.g_e':1})
```

But I know that this index can take on only about 60 text values. Does mongo figure that out, or is there a more efficient way to index this?

Answer (score -1):

You can put as many or as few words into a text index as you want to.
What you have to ask yourself is wether you want a full text search on the fields you put into your text index (you can have only one per collection).

If you don't need a full text search and only compare a finite set of values against the indexed documents, you already did it right, given that you do not want to sort by a different field of the document. In that case you'd have to put that field into the index (order matters!):

```js
db.collection.createIndex({"v_.g_e":1,"fieldToSortBy":1})
```

Comment: for order matters, if I have a compound index with say 6 fields, and only query on five out of them (but in the order they are listed sans the one I didn't include), does it slow the query? Or should I create an index with just five fields

Comment: @jwillis0720 MongoDB can and will use compound indices even when only some of the indexed fields are used. However, a compound index with six fields sounds a bit like there could well be a modeling problem. Having a field indexed for sorting, for example, when the query part already reduces the document to just a few and/or the documents are returned as a whole is usually a waste of precious RAM.

Comment: but, would a new compound index with only five fields be faster. That's all i'm asking.

Comment: @jwillis Eh, how should that be?

Comment: If I have a compound index of six fields, and query for only five fields, it will use the indexes. But if I made another compound index with just the five fields I queried by, would it be faster because it would use that five member index rather than the six member.

Comment: @jwillis0720 Erm, no. Since order matters. MongoDB's query optimizer will figure out that it has to traverse only the first five trees of the six-field-index when determining the best query plan (and cache the best query plan after the first query). So if your query obeys the order of the index, you are fine. Actually, when optimizing indices, you try to find exactly those cases to minimize the RAM needed for indices to prevent them being swapped to disk.